# Create Better Looking Buttons in VBA without using Image

Tags: winforms, vba, button, userform

Is there anyway to create more rounded/professional looking buttons using vba. I found a couple places that suggested using images, which is not a terrible Idea, but I was wondering if anyone had a clue if there is a downloadable software, add-in, or anything. The ones currently available make my program look like an Mid 90's application. I really appreciate the help. I mean look at it!!

[image]

Comment: Great question! I've never found anything but would also like a download or addin to solve that problem.

Comment: Right I I have used the Images, but sometimes because they are 2D they just don't work I have tried different approaches to. I just wanna make them a bit more modern.

Answer (score 5):

Office VBA uses the Microsoft Forms Engine which is a lightweight (drawn) implementation of a GUI toolkit. Because of this the usual techniques used to customise button appearance on windows (owner-drawing/theming) don't apply and your stuck with what you've got.

If you don't want to use images you need to find an ActiveX control that does the job, something like http://www.arcadiahome.com/products/components/activex/powerbutton.htm .

Comment: thanks for the information this will for sure help me in making a better looking application. Thanks

Comment: BTW if you go the activex route you need to install the corresponding .ocx on every machine running the app